# Use ORDER BY LENGTH query in JPA

Tags: sql, jpa

Is there a way to use the SQL 
'ORDER BY LENGTH` in JPA (Spring)?
We're trying to eliminate the usage of native queries.

Here is the native query:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnOne ORDER BY LENGTH(columnTwo) DESC LIMIT 1`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call functions in JPQL you use:

```
function(funtion_name, arg_1, arg_2, arg_n)
```

So your query would become:

```
select t from table t where t.columnOne order by function('length', t.columnTwo) desc
```

With JPQL you can't use limit in the query so you could use Pagination.